# Form regneration on every interaction, angular forms

Tags: javascript, angular, formarray

I'm having a problem with a Angular form. The problem is a checkbox, that contains some values (around 10). I have an item i push into this form with some allready selected values. So what I use the form to is editting/updating this item.

My checkbox right now can show which of the values in the checkbox were chosen before the edit. example here: https://gyazo.com/3cda89f3fc5c42de690fd8803274990b (hover to show)

But when I try to select a new checkbox value it just regenerates the whole checkbox every time, and I don't know why.

Maybe I'm filling the form on the wrong way, I'm creating the form like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="">Typer af data der indhentes:</label>
            <div formArrayName="DataTypes"
                 *ngFor="let test of this.createWhatItemData().controls; let j=index"
                 class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input type="hidden" />
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [checked]="test.value.selected" />
                            {{whatItemDataTypes[j].Name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then it is initialized and filled like this:

```
private initFormWhatComponent() {
        this.form2 = this.formBuilder2.group({
            ConsentWhatItemDirection: this.whatItem.ConsentWhatItemDirection,
            ConsentWhatItemType: this.whatItem.ConsentWhatItemType,
            OrganizationIdentifier: this.whatItem.OrganizationIdentifier,
            Name: this.whatItem.Name,
            Description: this.whatItem.Description,
            DataTypes: this.formBuilder2.array(this.whatItem.DataTypes)
        });

        this.addWhatItemFormGroupWhatComponent(this.whatItem);
    }
```

This is to get the allready selected values into my checkbox, and if i console log eg. "test" in this function it logs every time i interact with the form.

```
createWhatItemData() {
        let _formArray = this.formBuilder2.array(
            this.whatItemDataTypes.map(s => {
                return this.formBuilder2.group({
                    selected: this.whatItem.DataTypes.some(x => x.Id == s.Id),
                    Id: s.Id,
                });
            })
        );
        return _formArray
    }
```

The values that are availible to choose is fetched from the database, and are then merged together with the item values sent to the form.

can anyone help me with fixing the checkbox so I can select new values and then update my item?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private initFormWhatComponent() {
    this.form2 = this.formBuilder2.group({
        ConsentWhatItemDirection: this.whatItem.ConsentWhatItemDirection,
        ConsentWhatItemType: this.whatItem.ConsentWhatItemType,
        OrganizationIdentifier: this.whatItem.OrganizationIdentifier,
        Name: this.whatItem.Name,
        Description: this.whatItem.Description,
        DataTypes: this.formBuilder2.array(this.whatItem.DataTypes)
    });

    this.addWhatItemFormGroupWhatComponent(this.whatItem);
    //return anything in here..
}
```

Comment: what about that?